# Covering map Problem and induced isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology

I don't know how to start the following question.  Any help will be appreciated!  Thank you!

Suppose that $S^1 \times P^2$ covers some space, and let $h$ be a covering
translation. Show that the induced isomorphism $h$ of $H_1(S^1 \times P^2)$
must be the identity.

Comment: You keep asking new questions...